# SQL different results from batch vs single select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've hit a stumbling block that no Google searches have been able to answer. I am building an SQL script to distribute to my users to upgrade a database for a newer version of my application. I auto-generated the script using Visual Studio v18 SSDT schema comparison tools, but I've heavily modified the script to do a lot of existence checking before dropping tables and such (so as not to destroy user data during the upgrade.) My problem lies with checking the sys.objects table for the existence of triggers and stored procedures. When running the entire script, the queries to extract those types of objects return less results than expected. For example, in the script below, the SELECT statement for getting all the triggers returns 0 rows. But, if I highlight just the SELECT statement, right-click-->Execute in SSMS, it returns 1 row as expected. What would possibly cause the script to return different results when run in its entirety versus single statements run ad-hoc via SSMS?

I've tried removing the `SET ANSI_NULLS...` and `SET NUMERIC_...` lines but I get the same 0 results when running the script.

Any other ideas?

```
USE CarrierAPI_seed;
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;

GO
--Create a temp table with all triggers.
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#CAPI_Upgrade_Triggers','U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping table... #CAPI_Upgrade_Triggers';
    DROP TABLE #CAPI_Upgrade_Triggers;  
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #CAPI_Upgrade_Triggers
(
    trigger_name nvarchar(255),
    table_name nvarchar(255)
);
GO

INSERT INTO #CAPI_Upgrade_Triggers (trigger_name, table_name)
SELECT
    s.[name] as trigger_name
    , sp.[name] as table_name
    --, s.*
FROM sys.objects as s
    INNER JOIN sys.objects as sp
        ON sp.[object_id] = s.parent_object_id
WHERE s.[type] = 'TR';
--ORDER BY trigger_name
GO

--Create a temp table with all procedures.
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#CAPI_Upgrade_Procedures','U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping table... #CAPI_Upgrade_Procedures';
    DROP TABLE #CAPI_Upgrade_Procedures;  
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #CAPI_Upgrade_Procedures
(
    [procedure_name] nvarchar(255)
);
GO

INSERT INTO #CAPI_Upgrade_Procedures ([procedure_name])
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id) as procedure_name
    --, *
FROM sys.objects as s
WHERE s.[type] = 'P';
--WHERE s.[name] like 'sp_%';
--ORDER BY s.[name]
GO

SELECT * FROM #CAPI_Upgrade_DefaultConstraints;
SELECT * FROM #CAPI_Upgrade_FKConstraints;
SELECT * FROM #CAPI_Upgrade_Triggers;
SELECT * FROM #CAPI_Upgrade_Procedures;

PRINT SUSER_NAME();
GO
```

Comment: If they are returning different results it's because the data is different. Perhaps when running it in solitude you are connected to a different database due to a prior `USE` statement in your batch that you've omitted when running it on its own (there's certainly one in your batch above). Perhaps the batch `DROP`s or `CREATE`s the trigger before the check, and hence why they give different results. with a [mre] we can do little more than guess here.

Comment: As a further explanation about the `USE` scenario, `USE MyDB; SELECT * FROM sys.triggers` and `SELECT * FROM sys.triggers;` could easily return different result sets if you are **initially** connected to the `master` database, as the former statement would check for triggers in `MyDB`, but the latter in `master`; those are 2 completely different databases.

Comment: @larnu point taken about different databases. I'll troubleshoot that angle and report back. However, this isn't a reduced example, per se. This is exactly the first section of my script, and it exhibits the behavior I described. Thanks,

Comment: Then I suspect you are running the `SELECT` in the wrong database dur to "skipping" the `USE`.

Comment: @Larnu it was indeed I am connecting to a different database when running the SELECT ad-hoc. If I add a line `PRINT DB_NAME();` just under the SELECT and run it as part of the ad-hoc selection, it returns a different DB name than in the USE statement. Now I know what to pursue here. Thanks for your help.